# Does Bristleback's passive block Huskar's Burning Spear?

Tags: dota-2

Does it? And what type of damage does it block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wiki states that:

> [Bristleback takes less damage from all damage types except HP removal.](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Bristleback)

As Huskar's flaming spears are [magical damage](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Huskar), it should indeed block it.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that Spears are HP removal.. I'm pretty sure I 've read that somewhere.

Comment: @evil They are, but only on the damage Huskar deals *himself*.  Any damage to an enemy from burning spears is magical damage.  (The ability icon ingame states they deal magic damage, as well as the wiki page I linked)

Comment: thanks a lot. so on Huskar they are dealing HP removal. Okay. :)

Comment: But how about pure damage?

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak I quote from [the wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Damage_types#Pure): "[Pure damage]  interacts normally with abilities that reduce all incoming damage, such as...Bristleback"